# Saving updated xml without beautifulsoup.prettify

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I have created this code to substitute some strings in xml file with other text. I used Beautifulsoup for this excersise and as instructed in the documentation i used soup.prettify in the end in order to save changed xml. However prettified xml is not working for me - i get errors when trying to import it back to the CMS.
Is there any other way to save updated xml without changing xml structure and without re-writing the whole code. See my code for reference below. Thanks for advice!

```
import openpyxl
import sys

#searching for Part Numbers and descriptions in xml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
infile = open('name of my file.xml', "r", encoding="utf8")
contents = infile.read()
infile.close()
soup = BeautifulSoup(contents,'xml')
all_Products = soup.find_all('Product')


#gathering all Part Numbers from xml
for i in all_Products:
    PN = i.find('Name')
    PN_Descr = i.find_all(AttributeID="PartNumberDescription")
    PN_Details = i.find_all(AttributeID="PartNumberDetails")


for y in PN_Descr:
    PN_Descr_text = y.find("TranslatableText")
    try:
        string = PN_Descr_text.string
        PN_Descr_text.find(text=string).replace_with("New string")
     except AttributeError:
        print("Attribute error in: PN Description for: ", PN)
        continue

for z in PN_Details:
    PN_Details_text = z.find("TranslatableText")
    try:
        string = PN_Details_text.string
        PN_Details_text.find(text=string).replace_with("New string")
    except AttributeError:
        print("Attribute error in: PN Details for: ", PN)
        continue

xml = soup.prettify("utf-8")
with open('name of my file.xml', "wb") as file:
    file.write(xml)
```

Comment: What error did you got? You don't have to call `.prettify()`, just open the file without `b` flag and do `file.write(str(soup))`

Comment: Thanks! It worked! I don't know why i decided that i need .prettify(), read it somewhere online.